# How beacon can send a notification on device without any app?

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, beacon

I want to send a notification on that mobile which is in the range of beacon without any app and bluetooth is on.

Is it possible to send the notification?

Right now I'm using alt beacon library.

Comment: How would that work? Bluetooth on doesn't mean that the phone is scanning all the time. How would the phone know what to display?

Comment: Bluetooth is turned on or off whatever @TimCastelijns

Answer (score 4):

The closest you can come to doing this on Android devices is to **use a beacon to advertise an Eddystone-URL frame.**  Users with newer versions of Chrome for Android who have opted in to receive physical web notifications will see a notification to show the page of the URL transmitted by your beacon when Chrome detects it.

You can read more [here](http://blog.chromium.org/2016/02/the-physical-web-expands-to-chrome-for_10.html?m=1).

There are lots of caveats.  Users must have Bluetooth on, must have a newer version of Chrome installed, and must have enabled this feature.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's possible to send notifications without app if your beacon device supports [Eddystone-URL](https://developers.google.com/beacons/eddystone) protocol. On Android devices version 6.0 and later [Google Nearby](http://developers.google.com/nearby/) feature should be [enabled](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6260286?hl=en). For earlier Android versions, it's possible to use [Physical Web](https://google.github.io/physical-web/) feature on Chrome browser. For iOS devices with iOS version 8 and later and installed Chrome browser, Physical Web feature is also [available](https://docs.pushmote.com/docs/how-to-enable-chromes-physical-web-extension-on-the-ios).